# How to make a Function with Conditional Statements to determine what a button does when pressed? (React Native)

Tags: function, react-native, button, conditional-statements, onpress

Here is my current app.js file. I would like for the button to "know" which dropdown menu item is selected, and then pick a random song from a list and write that song name on the screen.

Currently, no matter which "mood" you have selected, it will output only "happy song" names in the console.

I believe my error is somewhere in my If/If Else statements, but after a few hours of debugging/googling, I could not find what the problem was.

Basically, I need a function to call onPress of my button, and in that function, I need it to determine which dropdown is selected, and only output a single, random, song from that "mood" of songs. However, my current function, "macSong" will always output a "happy" song, even if the dropdown menu has something else selected.

If anything about my question is confusing, please write a comment below and let me know what I need to elaborate on, Thanks!

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import SearchableDropdown from 'react-native-searchable-dropdown';

var items =[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Happy Music'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Sad Music'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Chill Music'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Hype Music'
    }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.screen }>
      <Fragment>
        {/* Title */}
        <View style={ styles.title }>
          <Text> Which Mac Miller Song Matches Your Mood? </Text>
        </View>
          {/* Single Dropdown Menu */}
          <SearchableDropdown
            onItemSelect={(item) => {
              const items = this.state.selectedItems;
              this.setState({ selectedItems: [...items, item]});
            }}
            containerStyle={{ padding: 25, alignSelf: 'center' }}
            onRemoveItem={(item, index) => {
              const items = this.state.selectedItems.filter((sitem) => sitem.id !== item.id);
              this.setState({ selectedItems: items });
            }}
            itemStyle={{
              padding: 10,
              marginTop: 2,
              backgroundColor: '#ddd',
              borderColor: '#bbb',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderRadius: 5,
            }}
            itemTextStyle={{ color: '#222' }}
            itemsContainerStyle={{ maxHeight: 140 }}
            items={items}
            defaultIndex={2}
            resetValue={false}
            textInputProps={
              {
                placeholder: "What kind of music do you want to hear?",
                underlineColorAndroid: "transparent",
                style: {
                    padding: 12,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#ccc',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                },
              }
            }
            listProps={
              {
                nestedScrollEnabled: true,
              }
            }
        />

      {/* Button */}
      <View style={ styles.button }>
        <Button
          title="Press me for a Mac Miller song!"
          onPress={() => 
            this.macSong()}
        />
      </View>
      </Fragment>
      </View>
    );
  }

  /* Different Mood Function */
  macSong(selectedItems) {
    console.log(this.state.selectedItems)
    if (this.state.selectedItems.includes('Happy Music')) {
      let songs = ['best day ever', 'kool aid & frozen pizza', 'nikes on my feet']
      let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
      console.log(song);
    } else if (this.state.selectedItems.includes('Sad Music')) {
      let songs = ['self care', 'ROS', 'stay', 'whats the use']
      let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
      console.log(song);
    } else if (this.state.selectedItems.includes('Chill Music')) {
      let songs = ['good news', 'claymation', 'the star room']
      let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
      console.log(song);
    } else if (this.state.selectedItems.includes('Hype Music')) {
      let songs = ['donald trump', 'remember', 'weekend']
      let song = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
      console.log(song);
    } else {
      console.log("Selected Item is Unknown")
    }
  }
}

{/* StyleSheet */}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    backgroundColor: ''
  },
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  title: {
    padding: 30,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onItemSelect={(item) => {} method you are mutating your state by putting reference to this.state.selectedItems to "items" constant and pushing a new value to it, you should make it immutable like this:

```
onItemSelect={(item) => {
  const items = this.state.selectedItems;
  this.setState({ selectedItems: [...items, item]});
}}
```

And then inside your Difference moods function you are using single "=" which means assign, not compare. Just use

```
if (selectedItems === 'Happy Music'){
```

inside your if statements and i guess it will work as you expect

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate it. The only problem after making these changes, no matter what mood is selected, I get the "Selected Item is Unknown" message, meaning that there is not a drop down selected? or at least not being compared properly. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Oh selectedItems is an array and you are comparing it with a single string value, try to rewrite your if statements to: if(this.state.selectedItems.includes('Chill Music')) {}

Comment: That makes sense, but do I need to change where the function is or what the parameter is? I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedItems' of undefined"

Comment: It means "this.state" isn't available inside scope of macSong function, you have to change your button onclick method by either using arrow function: onClick={() => this.macSong()} or using binding: this.macSong.bind(this)

Comment: Im assuming you meant onPress instead of onClick because onClick did nothing, but onPress gives me the console output of "selected item is unknown" again with both the arrow onPress function and when using binding. Any other thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: Try to console log "this.state" at the beginning of macSong function, you either made a mistatke updating ur selectedItems array and it's empty or your "if" statements never pass. Update your question with current code if you won't make it because atm it's hard to tell what you already changed :)

Comment: I have updated the code, i will try to console log this.state right now

Comment: Now you are using arrow function AND binding, but your code only binds a scope without actually calling the function. With current code you could do "() => this.macSong.bind(this)()" but it has no sense becase in arrow function you are already in a scope that you want, so just do "() => this.macSong()", without binding

Comment: okay sorry, I'm still learning js and trying to learn react on top of it lol, so i changed the function by getting rid of the ".bind" and the "this" in parenthesis. It is now printing the "this.state" but it still says "selected item is unknown", as if it is not passing any if statements. I will update the question with the new code again to make things easier

Comment: No problem, and remember that "Happy Music" !== "Happy" :)

Comment: I thought I was able to put just "happy" because it is an includes method, but thank you for clearing that up, I have changed them all back to have "music" at the end. However, I am still getting the same output, showing that the if statements are not working.